# HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath It returns a wrong path (DirectoryNotFoundException: Cannot find a part of the path)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, httpcontext

I am studying with ASP.NET Web Api on .NET 4.8.1 and I want to upload files to the `App_Data` folder of my project in `D:/Repo/Tests009...` by creating root with

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data")
```

This returns this path:

```
 C:/Users/MyName/Source/Repos/ProjectApi
```

But I get this errors:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Cannot find a part of the path:
>
> InvalidOperationException: Stream provider of type 'MultipartFormDataStreamProvider' threw an exception.
>
> DirectoryNotFoundException: Cannot find a part of the path 'C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\tests009\WebApi\App_Data\BodyPart_d0728dbb-09a1-45e3-96b4-b15c808ab7b5'.

This is my code:

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Files/Upload")]
    public async Task<string> Upload() 
    {
        var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try 
        {
           await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (var file in provider.FileData) 
            {
                var name = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;

                //remove double qoutes from string
                var localFileName = file.LocalFileName;
                var filePath = Path.Combine("~/App_Data", name);

                File.Move(localFileName,filePath);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

        return "File Uploaded!";
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it very much if you help me to get the actual path of my project.

My intention is to send a file to the `App_Data` folder of my project, but the `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` generates a wrong path for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. So, I see 2 bugs in this line

```
var filePath = Path.Combine("~/App_Data", name);
```

1 quotes have to be removed from file name when generating "resulting" file path, seems that fileName taken from "file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName"  contains excessive quotes, f.e. ""file.xlsx""

2 "resulting" file path should be absolute, not relative, so there you have to utilize Server.MapPath together with Path.Combine

Please replace that line with following one to make your sample working:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), name.Substring(1, name.Length - 2));
```

Probably you have to check if file with same name already exists. And quotes truncation should be done more "gracefully" with some checks (not sure that file names always comes with quotes)

Comment: Thank for your help. 
But I forgot to mention that the error message comes from above, especially here: `await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);`